# Deep copy only works properly when stepping into method

Tags: c#, serialization, copy, clone, deep-copy

I have implemented a deep copy method, when stepping into this method - the class is copied as expected.

However if i step over the method and inspect the class instance, some of the properties are not copied correctly.

```
Profile profile = new Profile();
profile = Model.Copy<Profile>(Profile.GetProfileById(ProfileID));
profile.Save();
```

The above code shows where the class instance is created and the copy is called.

Conforming with the database, the profile I require to copy has 2 items in the `AddressCollection` property.

If I put a breakpoint on the line `profile.Save()` and step over the copy method, the instance isn't copied properly and the `AddressCollection` property has 0 items.

However if i actually step into the copy method, the instance is copied properly and returns the `AddressCollection` with 2 items.

**Copy Method**

```
public T Copy<T>(T oldObject) where T : CRMBusinessObjectBase
{
    return Copy<T>(oldObject, null, null);
}

public T Copy<T>(T oldObject, CRMBusinessObjectBase parentObject, string parentProperty) where T : CRMBusinessObjectBase
        {
            //Create copy of business object
            T copy = null;

            System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter sz = new System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter();

            //Serialize and then deserialize to a new object
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                sz.Serialize(ms, oldObject);
                ms.Position = 0;
                copy = (T)sz.Deserialize(ms);
            }

            //Set business object as new
            copy.SetAsNew();

            //Set parent property if specified
            if (parentObject != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(parentProperty))
            {
                copy.GetType().GetProperty(parentProperty).SetValue(copy, parentObject, null);
            }

            return copy;
        }
```

I have tried changing the `BinaryFormatter` to use a `DataContractSerializer` without any luck. 
I have also tried to use reflection instead of serialization and the same problem occurs.

Not too sure where the problem could be.

**Screenshots**

Before the copy
[image]
After the copy
[image]

Comment: Perhaps the properties aren't attributed as `Serializable`?

Comment: The class is `Serializable`, this cannot be applied to properties

Comment: You're right. Sorry. But you could have attributes of types that aren't serializable or specifically marked some attributes as non serializable. But I think you would've allready checked that

Comment: Yeah they're all serializable. It's weird because the method actually works when I step into it, just doesn't when I step over it. Doesn't make sense at all!

Comment: Do you have any entries in your Watch Window? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa290869(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: Yes I have entries until the clone is called, then properties which are collections are all set to 0

Comment: @mjwills yes - I've added them to the question

Comment: Actually no it doesn't work if i don't hover over the variables - but it does work if i do hover over the variables. Kind of getting somewhere now, although i don't understand what is going on.

Comment: When you are debugging through it, with Watches etc, it is accessing properties of the object which is likely eager loading some properties / collections etc. Without hovering or Watch window then that isn't occurring. Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20760541/data-access-from-entity-framework-works-during-debugging-but-not-on-live

Comment: @mjwills Thanks for that. This is starting to make a little more sense

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue is likely related to the use of the Watch window, or hovering over variables while debugging.

See http://dotdotnet.blogspot.com.au/2010/04/lazy-load-eager-debugging.html :

> Another thing is that debugger and specifically Visual Studio Watch
>   window is not so friendly to lazy loading because the Watch window try
>   to evaluate the value of each property which cause all the lazy
>   loading properties to be loaded.